# Why am I seeing CheckMX deprecated warning?

Tags: symfony

I am seeing the following warning in symfony's profiler:

User Deprecated: The "checkMX" option is deprecated since Symfony 4.2.

I would like to know how to get rid of the warning, thanks.

I am not clear where this is coming from?  In the trace it points to the following code in one of my repositories.

```
    /**
     * @return Ride[] Returns an array of Ride objects
     */
    public function findRidesByYear($year)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->andWhere('r.date >= :year')
            ->setParameter('year', $year)
            ->orderBy('r.date', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

Specifically it is highlighting the getResult() function as shown in the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This a deprecation that was introduced in Symfony 4.2 on the `@Assert\Email` validation, which you are probably using. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html#checkmx

The reason for the deprecation are given in the docs:

> This option is not reliable because it depends on the network conditions and some valid servers refuse to respond to those requests.

You can fix the deprecation by removing the option from the assertion usage, e.g. in your entities. Instead you can use the `strict` option that uses a different library `egulias/email-validator` to perform a strict validation for the email address.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/4.x/reference/constraints/Email.html#checkmx